# problem of separation of read and write operation to aurora db

Tags: transactions, amazon-aurora, read-write

thought of trying to separate read and write,
using save method of orm such as typeorm,
it executes write and read operation just sequentially.

Since it is a method of reading from replicas, wouldn't there be a problem in reading the data immediately after writing it???
What do you think?